# A particular .js blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, smartgwt

My gwt application generates multiple .js files.This application serves multiple users across various geographies and locales.My problem is that a particular organisation faces a problem while loading one particualr js(named isc_core.js). All users in that organisation face that problem over some time difference.

We fail to understand why only one organisation fails to load the same js over and over again.

Multiple points for consideration - we have browser caching of one month for our .js files and a third party caching for serving our js across different geographies.

Comment: Is the organization experiencing the trouble using any security software that might have determined that that particular JS file is malicious and thus should be blocked?  If someone in that organization tries to load the full URL directly to the `isc_core.js` file in their browser, does the code successfully load and show in the browser?  Are you 100% sure that you don't have any HTML errors in your page (such as mismatched tags) that could be tripping up either the browser this organization uses or some security software that it uses?

Comment: Hitting the url directly loads the js correctly. And they face the problem with all the browsers. Although HTML tag tag mismatch hint is good,We'll verify that too.

Comment: Then, the issue is likely something in your own web page that either triggers a problem in the company's security infrastructure or triggers a problem in the browser.  You haven't disclosed much info for us to go on there other than wild guesses (like unclosed or mismatched HTML tags).  Also, when you say "fails to load one particular js file", what is the EXACT observation and symptom?

Comment: About security software - I think if it was so , then it won't load the js even on direct URL hitting.Plus after initial loading the issue got fixed but now is causing problem again. It shouldn't have loaded ever if it had issues like that.

Comment: exact observation - We had a pop-up appearing for the user.On investigation , we found out that cause is the isc_core.js missing.The exact problem can be seen here :-
http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=24765

And if there is HTML tag issue then it would appear for that same browser in any organisation (our testing suit containes a scenario to check on all browsers) .Also the organisation in case faces the problem on all browsers.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using mixed case in the name of your .js files because some OSes are case sensitive for filenames and some are not?  I see that you're doing it for all your files so probably not what is causing this exact issue, but that is generally considered a bad practice.  And, you then refer to the name in your question in all lowercase, further confusing things.

Comment: Also, security software or caching software (like proxies) that scans incoming HTML looking for bad things or caching things can get tripped up by unexpected HTML causing it to block something or skip something.  That particular issue could be specific to only one company.

Comment: OK, so far you have it reported in all browsers in one organization only, but only when the script is loaded from your web page, not when it is loaded directly.   All issues point to something in your web page is causing a bad reaction with something in the organization's security or networking infrastructure (e.g. security software, proxies, caches, etc...).  It's even possible the issue is in the organization's ISP (though less likely there).

Comment: If you have the ability to run tests in this other organization, you could create a very plain simple web page on your server as simple as possible that contains the problem script tag and then put some other inline script in that page that tests for the presence of the troublesome script.  Then, try to load that page from the origanization.  If you cannot reproduce the problem in a very simple web page, then you have further evidence that the issue is caused by something else in the fuller web page.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.
1)Apology for the casing but this file is auto generated and not by my code so naming convention is what is adopted by Smart Gwt tool and not our dev team.But a lesson learned for future in this.
2)I'll try to use the steps you have pointed for further investigation without which we were clueless.
So thanks again for all the help.